# Edit, reload and redownload website in java?

Tags: java, web, jsoup

I have plans for a small application, to gather some data from a website.
The website have a few textboxes, in which you can write different numerical values, then click a button and an output value will be written on the page.
What i want the application to do, is to fill the textboxes, then "click" the button and gather the output data.

Now i'm only really familiar with java, but my guess is that it's better to write such an application in javascript?
Also if it's doable in java, should i then be looking at some custom libaries, apart from jsoup which i've already used?

I already sort of figured out how to download the html and extract the data i need using jsoup, it's writing the values back into the textboxes that troubles me.

Thank you

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an implementation of the DOM(Document Object Model, a data structure representing webpages as object trees) in jsoup that can help you to change the textboxes' values. If you're going to code your project in Java, then JSoup is the better choice to do the job.